# For loop continue looping only when a function inside is finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

Here is an function first getting a file list, for each file, it will call a ajax function to execute something:

```
    function getImagesList(folder) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "getImgList.php",
            data: {"data":folder},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var IsfirstLoggingItem = "true";
                for (var key in data) {
                    //alert (data[key]);
                    pdfToImgExec (data[key],IsfirstLoggingItem,folder,1);
                    $('#pdfToImgResult').append('<p>Processing ' + data[key] + ' <img src="loading.gif" height="20" width="20"/></p>');
                    IsfirstLoggingItem = "false";
                }
                folder == 'Incoming' ? getImagesList('result') : pdfToImgResult();
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
                $('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Error</p>');
                alert (t);
                releaseBtn();
            }
        }); 
    }
```

This is the callee function, it contains an ajax function to execute something

```
    function pdfToImgExec(file,IsfirstLogging,folder,round){
            var postString = file + '&' + IsfirstLogging + '&' + folder;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "pdfToImgExec.php",
                data: {"data":postString},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('#pdfToImgResult').html('').append('<p>Finish processing ' + file + '</p>');
                    } else if (!data && round < 4) {
                        $('#pdfToImgResult').html('').append('<p>Encounter error in processing ' + file + '  ， retrying ' + round + ' round </p>');
                        round++;
                        pdfToImgExec(file,IsfirstLogging,folder,round);
                    }
                },
                error: function(x, t, m) {
                    $('#pdfToImgResult').html('errpr');
                    alert (t);
                    releaseBtn();
                }
            }); 
    }
```

In short, the getImagesList function get a file list, for each file , call the pdfToImgExec function to do some ajax staff. The problem is , it will not wait the ajax staff finish but start the next loop .

That means , I would like to e.g. file1 running ajax staff => file1 finish ajax staff => file2 running ajax staff => file2 finish => check result

However, the current situation is file1 running ajax staff => file2 running ajax staff =>  check result => file1 finish / file2 finish

I have tried async:false, cache :false in both function but it seem no help, how to fix it? thanks

Comment: you could setup the callback in the `getImgList.php` as a setInterval based function that will loop when `pdfToImgExec.php` is done it's thing.  Are these the same backends?  Why is the backend not taking care of both of these operations if there is such a tight correlation between these two operations?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the backends can handle the order of execution without any php code?

Comment: i was giving you two options. the first option is a front-end way to control the loop by "monitoring" it via `setInterval`.  on the second option... If you control the backend then I would be making one AJAX request to one backend service that performs both steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to store your data

```
var dataArr=[];
```

In your first function, push data to array

```
function getImagesList(folder) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "getImgList.php",
        data: {"data":folder},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            dataArr = data;
            doProcessData();
        },
        error: function(x, t, m) {
            $('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Error</p>');
            alert (t);
            releaseBtn();
        }
    }); 
}
```

Function `doProcessData` Like this:

```
function doProcessData(itemDoneCallback, allDoneCallback) {
    if(typeof(itemDoneCallback)==undefined)itemDoneCallback=function(){};
    if(typeof(allDoneCallback)==undefined)allDoneCallback=function(){};
    if(arrData.length>0){
    var key = arrData[0];
            $.ajax({
                 //option here like your function pdfToImgExec
                 success: function (data) {
                     arrData.splice(0,1);//remove first data.
                     doProcessData();// call to process next data.
                     itemDoneCallback(); // callback to process some thing
                 }
            })                
    }else{
       allDoneCallback();// all done callback
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, and I would like to know if an php file contain 'exec ('....')' , will the ajax call execute success funciton after exec is done or only once the 'exec' command is called?

Comment: sorry, i don't know php :)